# Managing Search within data react native

Tags: react-native, search, autocomplete, react-native-flatlist

I am building a kind of list app. The list contains almost 100 items. so I need to add a search bar which facilitates user selection .
This is my code

```
const searchTitle = () => {
        const results = state.values();
        for (const value of results) {
           if (value.title == term) {

            const id = value.id;
            const title = value.title;
            const audio_url = value.audio_url;
           navigate('Show', {id, title, audio_url});
           }
        }    
    }
```

Search is working well but the issue that user has to type all the sentence I need to get some modification so the user can type only few words and either get a suggestions or autocomplete the search

any help will be highly appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: also if there is any  way to make user able to put some items in favorite list

Comment: To search if the sentence contains a term you can use includes() function. Change your condition to `if (value.title.includes(term))`

Answer (score 1):

For improving the search try the solution by Mahdi N:

```js
if(value.title.includes(term))
```

For adding a favourite list, you can maintain a new field in each item as `favourite` and assign it `true`/`false`.

Or you can have a favourite list with `ids` of favourite items.